# SQL ADD CONSTRAINT not working in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

I want to add a foreign key to my 'reponse' table

```
ALTER TABLE reponse ADD CONSTRAINT FK_5FB6DEC71E27F6BF FOREIGN KEY (question_id) REFERENCES question (id)
```

However when I try that Query I got that error

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`my_quizz`.`#sql-3f2_11d`, CONSTRAINT `FK_5FB6DEC71E27F6BF` FOREIGN KEY (`question_id`) REFERENCES `question` (`id`))
```

My database is named 'my_quizz'.

My 'reponse' table :

```
    +------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int(6)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| id_question      | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| reponse          | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| reponse_expected | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| question_id      | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

My 'question' table

```
    +--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(6)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| id_categorie | int(6)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| question     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| q_id         | int(6)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: The error seems pretty clear.  You already have data in the table where the foreign key condition is invalid.  What do you not understand?

Comment: I wanted to know if I can update the data that I already have ?

Comment: also the size of the columns is different, `question_id` is `int(11) ` and `question.id` is `int(6)`, they should ideally have equal size if you are adding a foreign key constraint between them

Comment: @harsh I changed the int and I still got the same error

Answer (score 0):

There are rows in table `response` whose `question_id` does not exist in column `id` of column `question`. You need to fix those before the constraint can be created, either by changing `question_id` in `response` to somethig that does exist in `question(id)`, or by adding the missing `id`s in `question`.

You can exhibit the offending values with the following query:

```
select r.question_id
from response r
where not exists (
    select 1
    from question q 
    where q.id = r.question_id
)
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, what are the `r` and `q` in that query ? Also my databse is linked to my symfony project, can I safetly change the name of my columns ?

Comment: @Hanse: `q` and `r` are table aliases for (resp.) `question` and `response`. This does not change the name of the columns.

Comment: Okay ! So that query shows me the question_id column, I should add these aliases to my ALTER query in order to make it work ?

Comment: @Hanse: it is not about your ALTER table statement. As explained, the query I gave you gives you the list of `question_id` that are missing in table `question`. You need fix this before you run create the foreign key - as explained in my answer.